# Convert .xlsx to .csv and save to specific directory

Tags: vba, csv, outlook, xlsx, outlook-2010

I have a scheduled task set up (in a separate program) which will email a .xlsx file. I have a rule set up that will save the email to an Outlook folder called 04_CFW REPORT

I need Outlook to open the file with Excel and save as .csv to a network drive.

This will happen at night, when i am away from the computer

The closest thing i've found is a function here:
http://www.devhut.net/2012/05/14/ms-access-vba-convert-excel-xls-to-csv/

but i have no idea how to put this function to use in a sub.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Would Powershell work?  You can set a Powershell script as a scheduled task to convert a CSV into an XLSX.

Comment: Powershell is very cool. I just googled "can Outlook events trigger Powershell scripts?" The reason is because I still would like the execution to be started by Outlook. Why? I suppose because I don't know exactly when the email, with the attachment, will arrive. It's based on a query which takes who knows how long, and is variable. I only know when the query will be executed.

Comment: Update: I got it working with PS. awesome advice thanks...just a few kinks to work out. Quick explanation of the sequence: 1. Email with attachments arrives at certain time in the early morning (this is scheduled with a separate program, simply queries database and results arrive by email). 2. OutlookVBA script saves & renames attachment. 3. Powershell converts .xlsx to .csv and puts in proper directory. 4. First program i mentioned finishes its routine from there.

Comment: Glad you got things working, but this site works by voting up helpful answers so that other people can find them.

Answer (score 0):

This might be a place to start.  Taken from [here](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2011/05/26/use-powershell-to-data-mine-your-outlook-inbox.aspx)

Then you can research into [creating a powershell job](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2012/09/18/create-a-powershell-scheduled-job.aspx) to run once daily and loop until the specified email subject is found.

Another point to consider, if you have permission Powershell can perform the SQL query and output a CSV which can be converted into an XLSX.

```psh
Add-type -assembly "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook" | out-null 
$olFolders = "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.olDefaultFolders" -as [type]
$outlook = new-object -comobject outlook.application 
$namespace = $outlook.GetNameSpace("MAPI") 
$folder = $namespace.getDefaultFolder($olFolders::olFolderInBox)
```

Then I can filter on Inbox items using, for example any unread items.

```psh
$folder.items | where {$_.UnRead -eq $true}
```

***EDIT, getting PowerShell to close Excel's comobject correctly.  It's a matter of properly releasing the COM object.  First (assuming this isn't done) we Save the workbook and Quit Excel.

Next we release COM objects from smallest (here the variable holding a range of cells) to largest (the Excel ComObject variable) in a loop should more than one iteration be required.  Now the last two lines I've noticed are not really required, but in testing scripts it's nice to do but run Garbage Collection.  Watch task manager to confirm it's operation.

```
$xlsObj.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs($xlsFile) | Out-Null
$xlsObj.Quit()

While ([System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($xlsRng)) {'cleanup xlsRng'}
While ([System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($xlsSh)) {'cleanup xlsSh'}
While ([System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($xlsWb)) {'cleanup xlsWb'}
While ([System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($xlsObj)) {'cleanup xlsObj'}

[gc]::collect() | Out-Null
[gc]::WaitForPendingFinalizers() | Out-Null
```

Comment: That may come in useful in the near future. I have the whole thing running sufficiently, as i mentioned above, but now i'm working on two things: 1. finding the appropriate event trigger for the Windows Scheduler. Doing a time schedule works but i'd rather use an Outlook event (having trouble identifying the right one) or maybe just monitoring the directory where the attachment is saved? 2. Having Powershell close Excel properly...tried this one http://powershell.com/cs/blogs/tips/archive/2011/11/15/closing-excel-gracefully.aspx  but no go. stop-process -processname EXCEL  works but is ugly

Comment: P.S. I'm trying to figure out how to format my comments on this site to highlight like they do in NP++ or PS ISE etc... new guy..

Comment: For code snippets, use the backtick ` to get `this`
Next, for blocks of code add 4 spaces to each line.  You can add a 5th space to allow for indenting.